# Как правильно получить модуль?

Tags: yii2

Пытаюсь решить вопрос со своим расширением [вот ссылка](https://github.com/Sirgalas/yii2-wordperss-menu) суть в чем мне надо выводить сформированное меню как есть пришел к выводу что это придется делать через `Menuviews::widgets([]);`
соответственно в директории своего расширения создал класс `Menuviews` который от наследовал от Widget 
вот схема расширения

```
assets  //директрория
    controllers     //директория
    messages/ru-RU/sirgalas/menu    //директория
    migrations  //директория
    models  //директория
    views   //директория
    MenuAsset.php   //асеты
    MenuModule.php  //сам модуль
    MenuView.php      //то с чем пытаюсь работать
```

для чего это делается что бы вот так

```
use sirgalas\menu\MenuView;
<?= MenuView::widget(['name'=>'HederMenuLeft']); ?>
```

получить сформированное меню
теперь стало проблемой получить сам модуль расширения в `MenuView` модуль называется `MenuModule`.
делаю это так

```
use sirgalas\menu\models\Menu;
use yii\base\Widget;
use sirgalas\menu\MenuModule;
class MenuView extends Widget
{
    public $name;
    public function init(){
        parent::init();
    }
    public function run(){
        $model=Menu::findOne($this->name);
        $module= MenuModule::getInstance();
        return var_dump($module);
    }
```

получаю `null` 
Возникло два вопроса 1 возникает ощущение что делаю говно код это так ?  2 почему не  могу получить `MenuModule`  в классе `MenuView`?

Comment: Вам надо явно создавать модуль MenuModule, прописав его в 'modules' в конфигурационном файле. (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov в config commona или frontenda?

Comment: Скорее всего во frontend, так как загрузка нужна для ваших виджетов. Попробуйте и туда, или туда, и посмотрите что выйдет.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov да вы оказались правы но в целом вся логика расширения была не правильна и я её переделал, по другому, но вы дали правильный ответ можете писать подтвержу вам.